# Why does the `reset` command include a delay?

Tags: terminal

The `reset` command includes a delay, between clearing the screen and returning.  This is even on the latest terminal type `xterm-256color`.  Why?

`man reset` does not mention a delay, only the printing of special strings.  (It doesn't mention clearing the screen either.  I assume this is included under the terminal initialization string).

I notice the follow output in `strace -f reset`:

```
nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7ffe1964f100) = 0
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Real (hardware) terminals need that.  For instance, with some, the only way to reset them is to do a hardware-reset.

It's harmless with a terminal emulator, and since there's no conventional way to tell the difference (and too hard to determine if some escape sequence might do a hardware-reset), `reset` assumes your terminal is real.

The time-delay dates back to `tset` in 3BSD in 1979, like this:

```c
    /* output startup string */
    if (!RepOnly && !NoInit)
    {
            bufp = buf;
            if (tgetstr("is", &bufp) != 0)
                    prs(buf);
            bufp = buf;
            if (tgetstr("if", &bufp) != 0)
                    cat(buf);
            sleep(1);       /* let terminal settle down */
    }
```

It's evolved somewhat in ncurses, but using the same guideline:

```c
        if (!noinit) {
            if (send_init_strings(my_fd, &oldmode)) {
                (void) putc('\r', stderr);
                (void) fflush(stderr);
                (void) napms(1000);         /* Settle the terminal. */
            }
        }
```

Further reading:

- [*History*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h2-HISTORY) (**`tset`** manual page)
- [*History*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h2-HISTORY) (**`tput`** manual page)

Comment: While we're here could you explain how to remove the delay if possible?

Comment: @Mehrdad You could try `tput reset`. It doesn't seem to use the delay.

Comment: @Mehrdad sadly this doesn't do all the reset.  If you ctrl+C out of a password prompt for pkcon (or other polkit prompt), none of what you type shows on the screen.  I expect it fixes the other condition where you cat a binary file and your prompt turns into alien writing though.

Comment: @Mehrdad `stty sane` appears to fix the first condition, without any delay.

Comment: The release (6.0) of ncurses doesn't modify terminal modes (as "reset" or "stty sane" does).  currrent ncurses "tput reset" does all but the delay.  For OpenBSD... wait 10 years.

Comment: @Mehrdad this works fine for me: `alias reset='tput reset'`  in ~/.bashrc