# any reason to NOT "alias reset=tput reset" in .bashrc?

Tags: terminal, bashrc

"tput reset" is much faster than "reset" (as discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335648/why-does-the-reset-command-include-a-delay)), and running "reset" is annoyingly slow, is there some reason why i shouldn't add `alias reset=tput reset` in .bashrc ? is it likely to break something?

Comment: The alias won't affect anything except your interactive session.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are **not** using a real hardware terminal, as mentioned in the answer(s) to your linked question, there is probably no need to worry about it.

Note that rather than being an alias, typically the `reset` command starts out as a **symlink** to the desired utility; then that utility's executable detects which name you ran it with and changes its behavior accordingly. ([Busybox](https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#design) is a famous example of this technique.)

So it's theoretically possible that `alias reset=tput reset` wouldn't have quite the same effect as executing `tput` via a symlink named `reset`. But at least with my version, the manpage says it should be equivalent:

> If  `tput`  is invoked by a link named `reset`, this has the same effect as `tput reset`. See `tset` for comparison, which has similar behavior.

The alias should give you the best of both worlds: you get the faster reset which is presumably not going to be a problem with the terminals you use, but leave the system-wide /usr/bin symlink alone in case other users or background utilities are relying on the `tset` behavior or option handling.

Comment: ```If tput is invoked by a link named reset, this has the same effect as tput reset. See tset for comparison, which has similar behavior.``` i don't believe it =/   run ```time reset```, then run ```time tput reset```, do you get roughly the same number on both of them? i doubt it =/  for the record, on my system: ```/usr/bin/reset: symbolic link to tset; time reset: real    0m1.002s; time tput reset: real    0m0.002s``` - running tput reset was 500 times faster than running the reset symlink to tput

Comment: @hanshenrik I'm not following. Since your `/usr/bin/reset` remains a symbolic link to `tset` then **yes** you would get its slower behavior, versus if it were a symbolic link to `tput` instead.

Comment: if using the symlink is getting the slower behavior, then the following is not true: ```If tput is invoked by a link named reset, this has the same effect as tput reset.```

Comment: @hanshenrik Your symlink is **not** causing `tput` to be invoked. Your symlink is causing `tset` to be invoked. Those are different programs with different behavior.

Comment: They are different programs, but since [2018](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-6.1.html) the "reset" feature in each uses the same code, gives the same result.