# How do I generate a particular (named) escape sequence for the current terminal?

Tags: terminal, ncurses, stty, terminfo

I recently saw a trick that let you sort of "generically" output terminal control codes (based on the current termcap/terminfo settings), but can't find it back. If I remember correctly it let you do something like

```
echo "$(some_command home)"
```

And what got echoed would be the actual bytes of the escape sequence that would cause one's `$TERM` to move its cursor home. What was that command?

Answer (score 1):

The command I had seen was `tput`. One could use it ± as in my question:

```
echo -n "$(tput home)"
```

But of course that particular example is redundant; it's wasteful to run the stdout of `tput` into an argument that `echo` will write to its own stdout. It might make a little more sense if you needed to generate a string of `echo -n "$(tput thing1)some text$(tput thing2)other text` — but as @icarus points out in a comment below, this would lose any **timing** tricks that `tput` knows about.

So the utility would best be called directly whenever practical:

```
tput clear
tput blink
echo "DANGER WILL ROBINSON"
tput bel
sleep 5
reset     # NOTE: this might be symlinked to tput also!
```

It is not a core/built-in tool, but is provided as part of ncurses and should be pretty widely available as a result. I found a [nice intro/overview](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_tput.php) that gives some background, showing related commands as well. And [this gist](https://gist.github.com/izabera/9903f9d942e2667ef2cb) contains a handy listing of all the named "capabilities" that could be output.

Comment: In general you don't want the `echo -n "$(tput home)"`, but just use `tput home`. Whilst uncommon these days tput can be outputting delays which are lost. It is also less efficient to start up a shell to capture the output of a command just to then output it again.

Comment: @icarus Thanks, hadn't considered the possibility of timing delays within sequences. I updated my answer to be a bit more explicit about this. Also, I added an aside comment about the `reset` comman —  although on my daily system (macOS) it is symlinked to `tset` rather than `tput`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335648/why-does-the-reset-command-include-a-delay (via https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546918/any-reason-to-not-alias-reset-tput-reset-in-bashrc) for more discussion regarding that side topic.